# $\mathbb{PR}^n$ differomorph to a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{(n+1)^2}$ describing matrices

Tags: manifolds, projective-space, fiber-bundles, symmetric-matrices, diffeomorphism

I am interested in why the functions $f_{ij} \colon \mathbb{PR}^n \to \mathbb{R}, \ [x] \mapsto x_ix_j$ define a diffeomorphism between $\mathbb{PR}^n$ and set of all symmetric matrices of dimension $n+1$ with trace $1$ and satisfying $AA = A$ and why $\mathbb{PR}^n$ is compact.

I understand everything except $AA=A$ and regarding the compactness I am not sure because I have NoPhD! :P

Comment: Isn't just $AA$ the square of $A$, i.e. $A$ is idempotent?

Comment: Yes, so you can put it!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You can call the property $AA=A^2=A$ the idempotence of A

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you didn't understand the meaning of the $AA=A$.

Comment: This is (sadly) not the problem :D

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb {RP}^n$? (There are various approaches.)